# Getting pixel values from lat/long values using ENVI

Tags: latitude-longitude, envi, pixel

I am using ENVI software to process satellite image. I have two images from two different satellites and I want to get the value of the same point in the two images. I got random points from the first one and I know the lat/long of each point.

How can I get the value of these points in the other image?

Comment: have you tried to link between the two images? (if they are georeferenced)

Comment: they are not georeferenced